# Se tiene que poner suscribe a cuando se hace un get con http en ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic, http, ionic4

Quiero hacer una peticion get usando Http de `@angular/http`, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se presione un boton se tiene que hacer una peticion donde la respuesta de la peticion no me interesa pero si manda informacion de la siguiente forma

```
this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/info/botones/${this.ubicacion}/${this.category}`);
```

Se supone que solo hacer esa llamada deberia funcionar mas sin embargo en el servidor no detecta nada, no se si estoy haciendo algo mal o me falta colocar algo o se tiene que poner el suscribe para que se haga la peticion?

Comment: Yo pondria el subscribe o promesa para detectar, el posible resultado o el error que esta tirando la llamada para poder solucionarlo.

Comment: Es raro ya que si solo se coloca asi no genera la peticion pero si le coloco el suscribe si lo hace, pero cuando me entregaron este codigo ya venia asi, entonces no se cual es el problema en si, puede ser problemas de versiones con nodejs o typscript?

Comment: quiza al inicio de la peticion get, falto agregar un return, "return this.http.get---"